# How do you transfer a variable defined in the main method of one class to another?

Tags: java, class

I have seen this done in many programs but I cant seem to follow the programming logic.

Lets say you have a simple class, ClassB. And in ClassB's main method you define an integer variable:

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stuff = 333;
    }
}
```

How can you transfer the variable to a different class, say ClassA, to be used.

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(stuff);
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain this to me in simple terms. I've been trying to learn this for 2 hours and cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: A typical Java program has only one `main` method. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Kas.C can you give me an example, a program where you have seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public static void main(String[] args)` is meant to be used as a starting point for a Java program. Probably it's better to rename one of your methods to something else.

The problem you are seeing, is that the scope of the variable `int stuff` is limited to the `main()` method of class `B`, because it is declared within the body of the `main()` method. In order to make it visible, you need to declare it as a public field (which can be static in your case).

I propose you change your program like follows:

```
public class A {

    public static int stuff;

    public static void initStaticMembers() {
        stuff = 333;
    }

}
```

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A.initStaticMembers();

        System.out.println(A.stuff);

    }

}
```

I renamed the `main()` method of `A` to `initStaticMembers()` and dropped the method parameters, since they are not needed in our case. In order to use the field `A.stuff` in `B`, the method `A.initStaticMembers()` needs to be called first.

Of course there are ways to improve this program, but I think you should learn Java one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have 2 `main` methods. Only one `class` should (typically):

**ClassA.java**

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        System.out.println(b.stuff);
    }
}
```

**ClassB.java**

```
public class B {
    public int stuff = 333; // member variable
}
```

You **instantiate** the second `class` in the first one, then you're granted access to its public **member variables**.